# X.file api does not exist

Tags: xtk

The api link to it is dead. Not sure the plan for it, but it's a good idea to have a file object that holds loaded file so that images and colortables don't have to be loaded every time it is needed.

Comment: Any idea what's being asked here?

Answer (score 0):

The API is back: http://api.goxtk.com/renderer3D.html

The X.file object is private. Sotring all the datastreams does not make sense since it's wasting memory. The parsing is the time expensive task, the loading not so much so there would be no gain.